# fetching object data into array gives error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, pdo

i am new to php pdo and im trying to make a tournamentcms which randomly generates matches by closing registration. i keep getting this error 
Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.
Does anyone know how to fix this or know what i did wrong?
all help is appreciated.

i've tried switching up fetch methods but did not change anything.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
?>
</head>


<?php
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE tournament_id = :id 
   ORDER BY RAND()");
   $stmt->execute([":id" => $_GET["id"]
]);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$values = array();

$amount = count($result);

for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i += 2)
{
$values[] = '(' . $result[$i]['id'] . ',' . $result[$i + 1]['id'] . ', :tournament_id)';
}

$values = implode(',', $values);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into game(player1, player2, tournament_id) values ($values)");

$stmt->execute([
    ":tournament_id" => $_GET["id"]
]);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('update tournament set active = 1 where id = :id');
$stmt->execute([
   ':id' => $_GET['id']
]);

header('Location:index.php');

}

?>
```

the outcome of this piece of code should be that when i close the registrations for the tournament. registrated players should get inserted to the game table in a random order so matches for the tournament get automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the error was thrown before trying to use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` fetch style. From the documentation of the `fetchAll` method:

> `fetch_style` controls the contents of the returned array as documented in `PDOStatement::fetch()`. Defaults to value of `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`)

Using it like in your code should not cause that error. If it still does it means the error might be thrown in some other place. You could give this a try:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$values = [];

while (!empty($results)) {
    $firstPlayer = array_shift($results);
    $secondPlayer = array_shift($results);

    if ($firstPlayer !== null && $secondPlayer !== null) {
        $values[] = '(' . $firstPlayer['id'] . ',' . $secondPlayer['id'] . ', :tournament_id)';
    }
}

$values = implode(',', $values);

// Please note that you must not wrap the resulted `$values` by brackets
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into game(player1, player2, tournament_id) values $values");
```

If the error is still thrown then try `$firstPlayer->id` and `$secondPlayer->id` but the reason of returning objects instead of associative arrays would be very strange as you already requested the array fetch style.